# Word for a cultural transplant

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word for someone or something that has been transplanted or moved to a society/environment/area that is unnatural to them. For example, if you were black and moved to an all-white city. I believe the word starts with an "s" if I remember correctly. Anybody know?

Comment: Do you mean relocate?

Comment: Someone/Something who/that is "out of place"?

Answer (score 1):

If you were black and moved to an all-white city, I figure you'd look ***singular***.

> singular: unusual or striking
>
> singularity: strangeness by virtue of being remarkable or unusual

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/singularity)

Comment: It is the one I have been considering posting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alien.

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alien):

> Definition of alien in English:
>   adjective
>   1. Belonging to a foreign country: an alien culture
>
> 2. Unfamiliar and disturbing or distasteful: principles that are alien to them they found the world of further education a little alien